# Model with the intercept fixed at 1: selection with 'glmulti'

Tags: model-selection, meta-analysis, aic, meta-regression

I am performing the following model selection in R using 'glmulti' (based on aicc values):

```
rma.glmulti.ran <- function (formula, data, random, ...) {
  rma.mv(as.formula(paste(deparse(formula))), Variance, random=  ~1 | Primary_Study, data = dat_S_ratio, method="ML", ...)
}

res.S_ratio <- glmulti(S_ratio - 1 ~ -1 + N_Total_e + MAT_e + MWT_e + MST_e + MAP_e + Biome + Duration.yr + F_type, data=dat_S_ratio, random = "+(1|Primary_Study)", level=1, fitfunction=rma.glmulti.ran, crit="aicc")
```

The selection works by selecting the best model starting from the one with more explanatory variables, namely:

```
rma.mv(S_ratio - 1.0 ~ - 1 + N_Total_e + MAT_e + MWT_e + MST_e + MAP_e + Biome + Duration.yr + F_type, data=dat_S_ratio, random= ~1|Primary_Study, V=Variance)
```

Although the glmulti function seems to work and best models are selected, the models yielded with the selection do not have the intercept fixed at 1 anymore, giving the following results:

```
> # Show 'top models' (all the models with less than 2 aicc units away from that of the "best" model)
> tmp <- weightable(res.S_ratio)
> tmp <- tmp[tmp$aicc <= min(tmp$aicc) + 2,]
> tmp
                                      model     aicc    weights
1               S_ratio - 1 ~ 1 + N_Total_e 78.89899 0.09472624
2       S_ratio - 1 ~ 1 + N_Total_e + MAP_e 79.80721 0.06015233
3       S_ratio - 1 ~ 1 + N_Total_e + MWT_e 80.07875 0.05251576
4       S_ratio - 1 ~ 1 + N_Total_e + MAT_e 80.52824 0.04194524
5      S_ratio - 1 ~ 1 + N_Total_e + F_type 80.56890 0.04110121
6 S_ratio - 1 ~ 1 + N_Total_e + Duration.yr 80.64420 0.03958246
> # 1st best model results:
> summary(res.S_ratio@objects[[1]])

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 211; method: ML)

  logLik  Deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc  
-36.3915  128.8114   78.7830   88.8386   78.8990  

Variance Components: 

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed         factor
sigma^2    0.0155  0.1244     73     no  Primary_Study

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 209) = 151.4668, p-val = 0.9990

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2): 
QM(df = 1) = 6.2538, p-val = 0.0124

Model Results:

           estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
intrcpt     -0.1597  0.0377  -4.2400  <.0001  -0.2335  -0.0859  ***
N_Total_e   -0.0005  0.0002  -2.5008  0.0124  -0.0010  -0.0001    *

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The results of the best model selected are not the same, of course, as the model with the intercept fixed at 1, namely:

```
> NS_ratio <- rma.mv(S_ratio - 1.0 ~ -1 + N_Total_e, data=dat_S_ratio, random= ~1|Primary_Study, V=Variance)
> summary(NS_ratio)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 211; method: REML)

  logLik  Deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc  
-43.9133   87.8266   91.8266   98.5208   91.8846  

Variance Components: 

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed         factor
sigma^2    0.0280  0.1672     73     no  Primary_Study

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 210) = 196.8260, p-val = 0.7337

Model Results:

           estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
N_Total_e   -0.0011  0.0002  -6.1828  <.0001  -0.0014  -0.0007  ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Do you have any suggests on how could I keep the regression fixed at 1 in my 'glmulti' model selection?

Thanks,
Gabriele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the intercept is included or not is controlled by the `intercept` argument of the `glmulti()` function. This is set to `TRUE` by default. However, if you do `glmulti(..., intercept=FALSE)` you will get an error. This is because one of the models in the candidate set is then `S_ratio - 1 ~ -1`, which is a model that doesn't have any terms on the right-hand side. This is currently not allowed with metafor. So, you have to catch this case and somehow deal with it. For example, this will catch this case and just fits a model with an intercept on the right-hand side.

```
rma.glmulti.ran <- function (formula, data, ...) {
   if (formula == formula(S_ratio - 1 ~ -1))
      formula <- S_ratio - 1 ~ 1
   rma.mv(formula, Variance, random = ~ 1 | Primary_Study, data = dat_S_ratio, method="ML", ...)
}
```

Then this should work:

```
res.S_ratio <- glmulti(S_ratio - 1 ~ N_Total_e + MAT_e + MWT_e + MST_e + MAP_e + Biome + Duration.yr + F_type, 
                       data=dat_S_ratio, level=1, fitfunction=rma.glmulti.ran, crit="aicc", intercept=FALSE)
```

Of course, one of the models is now the model where the intercept is actually estimated. You can figure out where this model ended up in the list of models saved with:

```
sapply(res.S_ratio@objects, function(x) x$intercept)
```

Not sure what you want to do with this model. You could leave it in the candidate set or consider removing it.

By the way, I removed the `random` stuff from your `glmulti()` call, since this was superfluous. Also, the `as.formula(paste(deparse(formula)))` part was unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wolfgang! The script seems to work fine now. Is it ok to exclude the 'random' part from 'glmulti()'? In this way it is neglecting the random model and just performing a fixed-effect model selection, that is not probably the best if I want to keep it random, isn't it?

Comment: The ``random = ~ 1 | Primary_Study`` part is already in the ``rma.glmulti.ran()`` function.